# Error in converting a json to a Record using 'constructFrom' method

Tags: ballerina

I get below error when trying to convert json to a Record using 'constructFrom' method.

```py
error {ballerina/lang.typedesc}ConversionError message='map<json>' value cannot be converted to 'news_impl:RolelessUser'
```

What is the issue with my approach? I have posted my example below (modified to post).

```java
import model;
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/jsonutils;

type AuthDAO object {

    public function getUserInfo(string userEmail) returns (model:User) {
        // This is defined to compare the the errorneous result with this successful one
        RolelessUser x1 = {
            userId: "qqqwww",
            emailAddress: "sam@gmail.com",
            firstName: "sammm",
            lastName: "rrr",
            age: "33",
            nic: "1212121",
            dateAdded: "2020-04-19",
            publicKey: "ssddff"

        };

        RolelessUser|error rolelessUserRecord1 = RolelessUser.constructFrom(x1);
        io:println("rolelessUserRecord:", rolelessUserRecord1);

        model:User user = {};

        json[] userInfoJson = [];
        io:println("in DAO: email:", userEmail);
        var userInfoTable = testDB->select(GET_USER_INFO, RolelessUser, userEmail);
        io:println("userInfoTable:" + userInfoTable.toString());
        if (userInfoTable is table<model:RolelessUser>) {
            userInfoJson = <json[]>jsonutils:fromTable(userInfoTable);
            io:println("JSON is josn 1: ", userInfoJson[0]);
            io:println("Test JSON is josn 2: ", x1);

            io:println("Roleless User Info: ", userInfoJson[0]);

            // this works
            RolelessUser|error rolelessUserRecordTest = RolelessUser.constructFrom(x1);
            io:println("Test rolelessUser  Record:", rolelessUserRecordTest);

            // this FAILS
            RolelessUser|error rolelessUserRecord = RolelessUser.constructFrom(userInfoJson[0]);
            io:println("rolelessUser  Record:", rolelessUserRecord);

            model:Role[]|error rolesArray = [];
            var userRolesTable = testDB->select(GET_USER_ROLES, model:Role, userEmail);
            json[] rolesJsonArray = [];
            if (userRolesTable is table<model:Role>) {
                rolesJsonArray = <json[]>jsonutils:fromTable(userRolesTable);
                rolesArray = model:Role[].constructFrom(rolesJsonArray);
                if (rolesArray is model:Role[]) {
                    io:println("User Roles:", rolesArray);
                }
            }
            if (rolelessUserRecord is model:RolelessUser) {
                io:println("YYY");
                user.firstName = rolelessUserRecord.firstName;
                user.lastName = rolelessUserRecord.lastName;
                user.emailAddress = rolelessUserRecord.emailAddress;
                user.age = rolelessUserRecord.age;
                user.nic = rolelessUserRecord.nic;

                io:println("reolseArray:", rolesArray);

                if (rolesArray is model:Role[]) {
                    user.roles = rolesArray;
                }
            }

            return user;
        }
        return user;
    }
};

type RolelessUser record {
    string userId = "";   
    string emailAddress = "";
    string firstName = "";
    string lastName = "";
    string age = "";
    string nic = "";
    string dateAdded = "";
    string publicKey = "";
};
```

Gives below output with the above mentioned error when calling getUserInfo() method.

```
rolelessUserRecord:userId=qqqwww emailAddress=sam@gmail.com firstName=sammm lastName=rrr age=33 nic=1212121 dateAdded=2020-04-19 publicKey=ssddff
in DAO: email:sam@gmail.com
userInfoTable:
JSON is josn 1: userId=qqqwww emailAddress=sam@gmail.com firstName=sammm lastName=dddk age=23 nic=1212121 dateAdded=2020-04-19 publicKey=ssddff
Test JSON is josn 2: userId=qqqwww emailAddress=sam@gmail.com firstName=sammm lastName=rrr age=33 nic=1212121 dateAdded=2020-04-19 publicKey=ssddff
Roleless User Info: userId=qqqwww emailAddress=sam@gmail.com firstName=sammm lastName=dddk age=23 nic=1212121 dateAdded=2020-04-19 publicKey=ssddff
Test rolelessUser  Record:userId=qqqwww emailAddress=sam@gmail.com firstName=sammm lastName=rrr age=33 nic=1212121 dateAdded=2020-04-19 publicKey=ssddff
rolelessUser  Record:error {ballerina/lang.typedesc}ConversionError message='map<json>' value cannot be converted to 'news_impl:RolelessUser'
User Roles:role_name=writer role_name=reader
Got userr info:roles= userId= emailAddress= firstName= lastName= age= nic= dateAdded= publicKey=
```

Comment: I don't think this is [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Somebody might be able to figure out what is the problem thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually due to an incompatibility between the expected field type and the actual type of the entry in the JSON object or missing/additional fields. Since all fields seem to be present in the JSON, it could be the former in this case.

Just to narrow down the issue you can access the individual fields from the JSON object and check if the type for each individual field is the expected type.

e.g.,

```
json jsonObj = userInfoJson[0];
io:println(jsonObj.userId is string); // and so on
```

You can also print out `userInfoJson[0].toJsonString()` to get a properly formatted JSON that may also help pinpoint the issue.

There's an [issue](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/14810) to track improving the error on such `.constructFrom()` failures.

Comment: Yes. Figured out the issue by printing userInfoJson[0].toJsonString(). The 'age' in RolelessUser was 'string' but the userInfoJson had it as int. Thanks for the hint.